# Which situations can cause a select to return a different order

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, select

What can cause SQL server 2005 to return the results of a `SELECT` in a different order.

**Note**:
I don't know if that matters but the query has an `Order by` clause on a **non-unique** column (Date column to be specific) and the table is a temp table.

**Edit**:
I know that the order is not guaranteed if I wont specify it, but it usually consistent until something happens.

I want to know what is this "something" that can happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ordered by a non-unique column, then after the guranteed ordering of that column, the order of the rows within a given group is not guranteed - as awm said, it's down to the database. An insert can change the order, joins can change the order, an update can potentially change the order.

If you want guranteed order, then specify a set of columns in your `order by` that will gurantee order.

Comment: @gil: I'm unaware of the internal proceedings, but can easily imagine that an update could be essentially a delete-insert combination internally (maybe that depends on the table structure, maybe on something else). I've never cared about that much actually. What I must remember and stick to is that *the order is not guaranteed* if not specified explicitly.

Comment: Accepted for actually answering MY question.

Answer (score 1):

If there are duplicate values in the `ORDER BY` column, then the order of those values is undefined.  The order is whatever the database finds most convenient, and it can change at any time for any reason.

Comment: That something could be anything at all, even an internal garbage collection, but it's most likely a table update or optimization.

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt, it really doesn't matter why it should change, if it ever does.

The query engine **specifically documents** that the order is **unspecified** if you don't actually specify it.

As always, the general advice on relying on undocumented behavior is **don't do it**!

Reasons why it might change (there are undoubtedly others, but why press your luck?):

- A recompile of the query
- Stale indexes gets updated
- Maintenance have run on the server, rebuilding indices

Comment: I know. I'll never do it. But i'm after a bug that I think is caused by the changing order.

Comment: So fix the obvious bug then, introduce a complete ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> I know that the order is not
>   guaranteed if I wont specify it, but
>   it usually consistent until something
>   happens.

I think you meant to say

> I know that the order is not
>   guaranteed if I don't specify it, so
>   it's always unreliable, no matter how
>   consistent it looks.

Anything that affects the query optimizer's decisions about the execution plan can change the order of unordered rows.